# Change value of control from resources

Tags: c#, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate in my Page.Resources which has a TextBlock where the Text Value is binded to a database. Is it possible to re-use the TextBlock control in code behind? I would like to pass the Id to another Page. (Win RT windows 8 app c#)

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Customized">
       <TextBlock x:Name="TextId" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resouces>
```

code behind:

```
TextId.Text = "test";
```

error:

> The name 'TextId' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Yes the namespaces are correct

Comment: Why don't you try to read the id from your data context (where the TextBlock also gets it from)?
How do you use the template? Is it an ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl or a DataTemplate of a ContentControl/Presenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to access that `TextBlock` control in code by name. Your `TextBlock` name is valid only in context of `DataTemplate` and within that context must be unique.  You have to remember that `DataTemplate` can be used in many places and repeated many times. But since it is data bound to `Id` property it will be better to use that straight from the object.